# Wrong cinder quota usage calculation - BUG

Tags: openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder

I am facing the issue with `cinder` volume usage calculation, you can see from the below output that the 10GB volume is in reserved status and total usage is not included this 10Gb. Is there anyway to clear this or update `In_use`, out actual usage is 67GB but cinder usage showing only 57GB and remaining marked as `Reserved`.

```
    cinder quota-usage 82eaddf1f348142cabbed0d2ff7e213a0
+----------------------+--------+----------+-------+
| Type                 | In_use | Reserved | Limit |
+----------------------+--------+----------+-------+
| backup_gigabytes     | 0      | 0        | 1000  |
| backups              | 0      | 0        | 10    |
| gigabytes            | 57     | 10       | 1000  |
| gigabytes_Local      | 57     | 10       | 1000  |
| per_volume_gigabytes | 0      | 0        | -1    |
| snapshots            | 0      | 0        | 10    |
| snapshots_Local      | 0      | 0        | -1    |
| volumes              | 6      | 1        | 10    |
| volumes_Local        | 6      | 1        | -1    |
+----------------------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, it has been reported under https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1515576